# Using a wait block to make agents wait until condition is true

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I am using a *wait* block to make agents wait until a condition is true (a resource is idle). I have tried writing the following in the *wait* blocks "on enter" field:

```
if(resourcePool1.idle()> 0){ self.free(agent); }
```

The problem is that if the resource becomes busy the agent will be trapped inside the wait block and will not be released, even if the condition becomes true again. Then when the next agent enters the *wait* block (and the condition has become true again) it will pass the agent that was otherwise in front of it, but that is now stuck. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you did is correct, but you have something missing.

Additionally to that, you need to do something like this in the resourcePool onrelease action

```
if(wait.size()>0)
wait.free(wait.get(0));
```

Then whenever a resource gets idle, you can release an agent from that wait block, if any exist there